# How to extend System.Windows.Input.Keyboard class

Tags: c#

I would like to add some additional methods to System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.I have tried to create a partial class like this;

```
namespace System.Windows.Input
{
    public static partial class Keyboard
    {
        //some code...
    }  
}
```

However when I try this Resharper informs me that this is not a partial file and when I try to use it I get an ambiguous reference error although both Keyboards are shown as being in the same namespace. Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if not, why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `Keyboard` is a **static** class.
Static classes cannot be instantiated and they cannot be extended.

You can always write your own (static) class and put your methods in there.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the same namespace as Keyboard, the class should be only static, you can name the class whatever you want "KeyboardExtensions" for exemple

See this for extension methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible because the Keyboard class is not partial to begin with.

The ambiguous reference is caused by the fact that you're creating a class that already exists in the same namespace so the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

You *cannot* create a static class that inherits from another static class as suggested by @harmoniemand.  Static classes can only inherit from Object.

And you cannot create extension methods on a static class as @Hamza_L seems to be suggesting because you can't use static types as parameters in extension methods.

Answer (score -1):

with a look at the manual, you could see that the System.Windows.Input.Keyboard is not defined as partial ([look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard(v=vs.110).aspx)) so you are not able to extend it this way.

The better way to do it, is to write an inherited class.

```
namespace MyApplication.Wrapper
{
    public static class MyKeyboard : System.Windows.Input.Keyboard
    {
        //some code...
    }  
}
```

Comment: Keyboard is a static class and is therefore `sealed`.  As such it cannot be inherited.

Comment: okay. but in the documentation its not sealed (public static class Keyboard). Sry for that. than the extension method is the best (only) way.